# How to upgrade python3 in venv in OpenSuse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a virtual enviroment in Opensuse. When it's activated, I tap python3 and I het the version that I have, python 3.6.15. I want the latest one, at least has to be a 3.7. But I use the following line to upgrade:

> /home/new/build/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade python3

And I'm getting the error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for
> python3

Thank you in advice!

Comment: You cannot update Python like this. You have to install the desired version on your machine and create a new virtual environment for it.

Comment: And how can I do it? In my machine I have python 3.9, I want to use this one. I'm starting the virtual enviroment like this: || python3 -m venv venv ||
cd venv/ ||
source venv/bin/activate ||

Comment: delete the existing virtual env directory and do `python3.9 -m venv venv` to create a PY39 venv